# How long does it take for a pokestop nomination to come into voting after being in queue?

Tags: pokemon-go

I am new in submitting pokestop  nominations. So I nominated 2 pokestops of my area. Almost 4 days passed , i still find it in queue in my niantic wayfarer account. I am afraid whether it is the procedure or an error occurred while submitting the nomination.

So,  how long did nomination take to get into voting from in queue.

What is the minimum and maximum waiting time it might be ?

If number of players matter , in this case, our town has almost 15+ players of pokemon go with level 38 or 38+ accounts along with me.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on a [discussion](https://community.wayfarer.nianticlabs.com/discussion/9462/how-long-does-it-take-to-approve-a-pokestop) on the Wayfair community site, the waiting period can range anywhere between a few days to a year; or even longer. Since Wayfair is community driven, it is at the discretion of the community to accept or reject a submission.

Highly populated urban areas will likely go through the review queue more quickly than less populated rural areas. Since there seems to only be a small handful of players within your area, your submission may not receive much attention.

I’m not familiar with Wayfair as a whole, but if possible, perhaps sharing your submission to an open-forum discussion community such Reddit or Discord may draw more attention.

Comment: How can I share  an in queue pokestop